# Code works in Spyder, not in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, typeerror, spyder

I have a piece of code that looks like it should work just fine. When I run it in jupyter notebook (v3.8.8) I get this - `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

I'll run the same code in Spyder (v4.2.5) and it works exactly as it should. Is there some compatibility issue or something going on? Have any advice as to why it would work on one platform and not another? Is there anything I can do to circumvent this so it works on my jupyter notebook?

```
# Grocery list and prices
food = ["Tostino's Party Pizza", "Lay's Classic Potato Chips", "Pepsi Soda, 2 Liter", "Tyson Any'tizers Chicken Wings"]
price = [1.50, 3.98, 1.98, 10.42]

#Calculating sum of groceries

total_price = []

for p in price:
    total_price.append(p)
print(total_price)

print(sum(total_price))
```

Answer (score 1):

So...someone from my class took a look at this and said the code should work as its written. They said running both Jupyter notebook and Spyder at the same time may be causing issues with the kernels. She suggested I interrupt the kernel at first, but that didn't work. Next, we tried to restart the kernel and run the code again, and it worked. I don't understand how these things work, but I'm glad I can get on with life now...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with a similar error but that was for 'generator' type. It was running fine in Spyder but not in Jupyter notebook. Spent two hours to understand the issue and finally after reading the note of redleg_64, just restarted the Kernel in Jupyter and it worked!